# Novel with a gravity gun which made the target collapse in on itself and disintegrate

Tags: story-identification, novel, gravity

Back in 2011-13, I read a short science fiction novel from the internet on aliens and our interaction with them. In that novel the main weapon of choice was a gravity gun which upon firing would cause the target to collapse in on itself and disintegrate. For example, if I fired it on a house, the house would slowly collapse into itself and vanish into thin air, meanwhile the surroundings would be unaffected.

Comment: This type of gravitational weapon is quite a common idea in hard SF so it's going to be hard to identify the novel on this alone. Is there anything else about the novel that you can remember.